# Passing arguments in ColdFusion Component

Tags: coldfusion

I need help determining the Coldfusion StructKeyExists function. Depending on the version I get different results. For instance:

I am Passing the argument as

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(arguments,'userid') and arguments.userid neq ''>
```

**It works**

now if i have the argument like this:

```
<cfif isDefined('arguments.structform.user') and arguments.structform.user neq ''>
```

**it Works**

if i pass above as:

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(arguments,'structform.user') and arguments.structform.user neq ''>
```

- **Coldfusion does not recognize it and skip it altogether**

Using coldfusion 10

Comment: `arguments` doesn't have a `structform.user` key. it has a `structform` key.

Comment: In none of your code examples are you actually 'passing' an argument, you are merely attempting to check for the existence of arguments - and ore accurately, you are attempting to check the existence of structure keys within one of your arguments.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Answer (score 4):

`structKeyExists` isn't recursive, it can only look for a key on the current struct. In your case, you'll need to test if `arguments` has a `structform` key, and then additionally check if `arguments.structform` has a `user` key.

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(arguments,'structform') and StructKeyExists(arguments.structform,'user') and arguments.structform.user neq ''>
```

---

It would probably be a lot easier if you just defined the argument.

```
<cfargument name="structform" type="struct" default="#{user:''}#">
```

Now you can assume the argument exists and just test the value of `arguments.structform.user`.

```
<cfif arguments.structform.user neq ''>
```

Even if you only defined the `structForm` argument with an empty struct, it would still be better than what you were originally doing.

```
<cfargument name="structform" type="struct" default="#{}#">
<cfif structKeyExists(arguments.structform, "user") and arguments.structform.user neq ''>
```

Comment: so using this the above you said, will it have some performance improvement on the `isDefined` Function

Comment: That i don't know. Test it and find out! I use Railo so me testing it may not give the same result that you would get.

Comment: My guess would be you'd find that you have to iterate hundreds of thousands of times to get any kind of measurable data, meaning the difference is negligible.

Comment: The difference is less about performance, and more about what happens when you use one method vs the other. using `isDefined()` could potentially find `local.arguments.structform.user` (if it existed) before it found `arguments.structform.user`. where as `structKeyExists` will only look through the `arguments` scope.